# API Platform, Posting an object with EmbedOne in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to save data in a MongoDB. That works so far. Next, I would like to save an object in this record via @ODM\EmbedOne / @EmbeddedDocument. What am I doing wrong?

API platform errors:

> "hydra:description": "The type of the \"device\" attribute must be \"object\", \"string\" given."

or

> "hydra:description": "Syntax error"

Or

> "hydra:description": "The type of the \"device\" attribute must be \"object\", \"array\" given."

api platform post example:

```
{
  "name": "AAA",
  "nameShort": "AA",
  "lastUpdate": 22332340,
  "device": "{"deviceId":200, "name":"Test"}"
}
```

Now a little bit code:

```php
<?php
// api/src/Document/Vessel.php

namespace App\Document;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\EmbedOne;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(iri="http://schema.org/Vessel")
 *
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Vessel
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id(strategy="INCREMENT", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type(type="string")
     */
    public $nameShort;

    /**
     * @ODM\Field(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type(type="integer")
     */
    public $lastUpdate;

    /**
     * @EmbedOne(
     *     discriminatorField="type",
     *     discriminatorMap={
     *         "device"="Document\Device"
     *     },
     *     defaultDiscriminatorValue="device",
     *     nullable="true"
     * )
     */
    public $device;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\EmbeddedDocument;

/**
 * @EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Device
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $deviceId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDeviceId(): int
    {
        return $this->deviceId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $deviceId
     */
    public function setDeviceId(int $deviceId): void
    {
        $this->deviceId = $deviceId;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to send an object for the "device" value instead of the string you are using:

```
  "name": "AAA",
  "nameShort": "AA",
  "lastUpdate": 22332340,
  "device": {"deviceId":200, "name":"Test"}
```